vendor/bin/mftf generate:tests AdminLoginSuccessfulTest error
I am facing the issue with MFTF testing. I want to submit my custom shipping module to marketplace but I got the error
MFTF Adobe Commerce Supplied fail.
how to test to my module and how to resolve the below error.
I have run the command to test and I got the below error if I have already create a .env and .credentials file.
vendor/bin/mftf generate:tests AdminLoginSuccessfulTest StorefrontPersistedCustomerLoginTest
error :
admin: not configured correctly in .credentials file
In SuiteObjectHandler.php line 132:
Suite Data Parser Error: Password not found in credentials fileInvalid Credential Storage. You need to configure at least one of these options: .credentials file, HashiCorp Vault or AWS Secrets Manager correctly.
Exception from File Storage:
admin: not configured correctly in .credentials file
generate:tests [-c|--config CONFIG] [-i|--time TIME] [-g|--groups GROUPS] [-t|--tests TESTS] [--filter [FILTER]] [-p|--path PATH] [-l|--log LOG] [-r|--remove] [-f|--force] [-a|--allow-skipped] [-d|--debug [DEBUG]] [--] [...]
Need help to solve this.
Thanks in advance.
